# Rails: Permanent url for active storage videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, rails-activestorage

I'm building a webapp which is offline available.
Therefore I need urls to images and videos were not expiring at any time.
ActiveStorage is not build for that case.

So I build my own media controller for serving images and videos based on the url `params`

```rb
get '/media/:kind/:type/:size/:token'
# /media/video/mp4/middle/ABC123
# /media/image/logo/large/ABC124
```

There is a MediaObject with a unique token. With the `params` I get the right variant of the image or the converted video file, look for the path of the blob file, seasoned with a quick lookup what filetype it is and serving it.

```rb
path = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, variant_by(size, type).key)

send_file path, type: content_type, disposition: 'inline'
```

everything is working good, very good. The images and videos got a cacheable (better looking) permanent url.

Now there is an issue with Safari. Every browser can handle the mp4/webm file the controller returns. Except of safari. The video cannot be watched in the browser.
I'm guessing, there is something missing in the headers.
But I cannot find the place in active storage where the videos served.

When I use the default way

```rb
# example
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(video.mp4)
```

the video can be played inline.

I've tried to add the content-length to the response header, add range infos and status `:partial_content`, add the file extension to the url, but nothing works.

The mime type is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 6 introduced a `public` option in storage.yml. Set it to true to override the expiring URL stuff: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#public-access

Also, if you're still on Rails 5.2, you should be able to use:

`rails_blob_url(imageable.image, disposition: :attachment)`

Comment: I think the public option only applies to variants and not originals?